# Delete picture in a carousel + update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'v a Carousel with the possiblity to update pictures (stored in db) and to view them in a bigger size. That works fine. But now, i would like to remove them. And that works almost. Almost means, the picture is deleted but the carousel is not correctly refreshed. Here is my code:

```
    <p:tab title="#{vms_uimsgs['vehicle.tab.images']}">
     <h:form id="pictures" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{vmsVehicleActionBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" update="vehiclePictureCarousel" sizeLimit="10000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
       <p:carousel id="vehiclePictureCarousel" var="imageId" value="#{vmsVehicleActionBean.imageIds}" itemStyleClass="vehiclePictureItem" effect="fade">
        <f:facet name="header" value="#{vms_uimsgs['vehicle.tab.images']}"/>
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%" cellpadding="5">
         <p:graphicImage value="#{graphicImageStore.streamedImageById}" rendered="#{graphicImageStore.hasImage(imageId)}">
          <f:param name="id" id="id" value="#{imageId}" />
         </p:graphicImage>
         <p:commandLink id="deleteImage" update="vehiclePictureCarousel" oncomplete="#{vmsVehicleActionBean.deleteImage()}" title="Delete Picture">
          <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="margin:0 auto;" />
          <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{imageId}" target="#{vmsVehicleActionBean.selectedImageId}" />
         </p:commandLink>                       
        </p:panelGrid>
       </p:carousel>
      </h:form>
     </p:tab>
```

Or asked differently, why is my carousel correctly refreshed when i add a picture with my file uploader and not when i remove one with a commandlink inside the carousel?

Of course, when a reload the whole page, everything is correct. But I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from `oncomplete="#{vmsVehicleActionBean.deleteImage()}"`, `oncomplete` is an attribute to call javascript method when ajax have completed, so you should use:
facelet:

```
 actionListener="#{vmsVehicleActionBean.deleteImage(imageId)}"
```

bean:

```
public void deleteImage(String imageId){
//delete here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution.